# Making a Shape Edge Vertical in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm making a letter M in Illustrator by using the pen tool and drawing half of the letter and then mirroring it with a transform effect. I noticed that when I zoom in there is a hairline space due to the fact that the edge is not 100% vertical. I've tried moving the anchor point around but I can't get it completely vertical even when holding shift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select two or more anchors and click the buttons on the **Align Panel** or the align buttons on the **Control Panel** across the top of the screen (if it's set to align to selection).

Or select the anchor points and choose `Object > Path > Average` and select the "Vertical" option.

Comment: If you are trying to align a single line segment with two anchors, then this doesn't work.

Comment: Correct @Chris However, you can easily add a third anchor temporarily.. align your two anchors, then remove the extra anchor. But, since the alignment options are always perpendicular, for a single line segment, you can merely use Smart Guides to ensure it's straight.

Answer (score 2):

Holding shift constrains the angle to increments (usually 45 degrees). So if your line is at 90.005 degrees it will increment to 135.005, 180.005 degrees, etc.

The quickest way to make a line completely vertical though is to select it and make sure the width is 0 in the **Transform Panel**. I actually use the panel often to make sure I've drawn completely vertical or horizontal lines because of how easy it is to access.
[image: Transform Panel]