# Make lines vertical/horizontal

Tags: inkscape

If I have a simple shape like this one in Inkscape

[image]

how can I make one segment vertical or horizontal to get to this result?

[image]

Comment: Here is a similar question for Illustrator: [**Making a Shape Edge Vertical in Illustrator**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/20559/8708)

Comment: move the bottom left corner?

Comment: I solved my problem with `guide lines` and `snap to cusp nodes`/`snap to guides`. But I had hoped, there was a simpler way to make lines vertical or horizontal.

Answer (score 5):

You could also select the top left and bottom left node, then align them using the Align and distribute dialogue. Then do the same with bottom left and bottom right nodes.